# Vaporizing water by piston work

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider you have an adiabatic container with a piston. At the moment, the the container has liquid water and air, of known mass, in the headspace at 1 bar and 298 K. Suppose I perform some PV work by pushing the piston down and increase pressure to 10 bar. I just did some adiabatic compression, so the system will be at some elevated temperature as well. I want to get a handle on the thermodynamic properties of the system. My questions are:

Can I say the process is isentropic since no heat is being lost to the surroundings? I need one more constraint apart from knowing the pressure ratio to define the system, right?

This is something I need clarification on. Back in undergrad, we dealt with psychrometric charts. Air has a certain capacity to hold water at a given temperature. My question is, will the vaporization of water be limited by this fact? Given the temperature we are at, the air in the headspace can only hold so much water? Or do I not worry about that and do my energy balance, H1 + W = H2, where H1 is the enthalpy at state 1, W is the work performed on the system and H2 is the enthalpy at the second state?

Essentially, can I have a mixture of A kg of air and B kg of steam at a given temperature, even though the psychrometric chart says that air can hold only C kg of steam (C < B)?

Comment: Air does not act like a sponge. The relevant parameters are the partial pressure of water and its saturation pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you can determine the final thermodynamic state of the system, the answer is yes, provided you know the details of how the external pressure is applied as a function of the volume.  The process is going to be isentropic if the added external pressure is applied gradually and in tiny pressure steps.  If it is applied rapidly, then the process will not be irreversible, and the entropy of the system will increase. For example, if the external pressure is suddenly increased to a new constant value, the work done on the system will be $-P_{ext}\Delta V$, where $\Delta V$ is negative, and the compression will be irreversible.

Your equation for the energy balance is incorrect.  It should involve the change in internal energy $\Delta U$ rather than the change in enthalpy, $\Delta H$.  If you are willing to assume that up to 10 bars, the gas phase mixture can be modeled as an ideal gas and that the dissolution of air in the liquid water is negligible, this problem can be solved rather easily either for the isentropic case or for the constant external pressure increase case.

Comment: Hi Chet. But regarding last paragraph of OP he should be using steam tables, not pyschrometric chart right? The chart only applies to atmospheric air, not 10 bar. That was something I intended to point out in an answer but hadn't completed it yet.

Comment: Yes, the psychometric chart should not be used.  The steam tables can be used, or, if some minor additional assumptions are made, the problem can be solved even without the use of the steam tables (if we know heat capacities, heat of vaporization, and vapor pressure vs temperature relationship).

Comment: I was also thinking about referring to use of ideal gas law, but felt uncomfortable about doing so when talking about steam, which is one of the reasons I didn't submit an answer.

Comment: @BobD what do you think the partial pressure of the water vapor is going to be at the final state?

Comment: For saturated water, 10 bar- no?

Comment: @BobD Not if there is initially air in the head space.  The answer is going to depend on the initial volumes of liquid water and air in the cylinder.

Comment: I was assuming saturated water at 10 bar. But since the heating of the water is essentially only the result of adiabatically compressing the air above it (being that the compression of liquid water alone results in an insignificant temp increase) based on some crude calculations we would need an initial mixture that is almost all air and very little water to be able raise the water temperature to the saturation temperature (180 C) at 10 bar. I can go over my calculations, but we probably should continue in chat.

Comment: Let's wait until we hear back from the OP.  I agree that very little liquid water would be involved in the situation you are describing.

Comment: Agree lets. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD I've introduced a Challenge Problem on this at Physics Forums.com.  Check it out under Mechanical Engineering.

Comment: Thanks Chet. I'll check it out.

Comment: I went on the Physics Forum. Found your diagram there but no Challenge Problem. Is there a separate Mechanical Engineer section on the Forum? Don't know where to  look for the Challenge Problem.

Comment: Mechanical Engineering threads as in the Enginneering forum (toward the bottom of the main menu)

Comment: Chet- Found it. Thanks.

Comment: @ChetMiller, and Bob D. So what I have going on is that when a certain amount of work is added to the system and the system is at 10 bar, all of the water evaporates and is steam. This has to mean that the temperature is at saturation. My question is, when we are doing the energy balance, how should I evaluate internal energy of steam? would I calculate $H_steam$ at $(T^{sat})$ and $y_wP^{sat}$, because the pressure due to steam is mole fraction times total pressure?

Comment: Why don't you see my Thermodynamics Challenge Problem thread  at physicsforums.com and provide some input?  I will help you work through the analysis of this problem there.  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/thermodynamic-challenge-problem.979038/. You were the one who motivated the development of this thread.  There have been no responses so far.

Comment: If all the water just barely evaporates, the vapor will be saturated.  If there is more than enough compression to evaporate all the water, the steam fraction will be superheated.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll get to it.

Comment: @ChetMiller, have responded to the question. Looking forward to hearing from you.